# HTML tag:label with onclick asp.net method.

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, forms

I have this form:

```
    <form id="form21" runat="server" method="post" onsubmit="return send()">
          <asp:Button runat="server"  ID="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-send" Text="עדכן" onclick="submit_Click" />
          <label ID="other" name="other" runat="server" class="btn btn-send" onclick="other_Click" Visible="False">נהל משתמש אחר</label>
    </form>
```

When I click on the label this error occur: "JavaScript runtime error: 'other_Click' is undefined".

How can I combine between asp.net method and HTML tag?

Comment: Where is `other_Click` defined? Label doesn't handle clicks on server side... not sure if you are trying to handle it on client or server side.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking. Can you post your Javascript code? If `other_Click` method is missing then you will get this error.

Comment: The other_Click is in the aspx.cs page. There is method with this name. So in other way, how can I control that only one button will do the onsubmit="return send();"?

Comment: If you have a new question then *ask a new question*.  Don't edit an existing question into an entirely different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From server perspective, this:

```
<label ID="other" name="other" runat="server" ...
```

is an instance of `HtmlGenericControl` class. This class and most of its subclasses does not have server-side click event. So the `onclick` you defined is not treated as server-side subscription and therefore rendered into the HTML as is. So on the final page is this just a JavaScript function call. And since you do not have such function on the client side, you get the error.

To resolve it you might want to switch to some sever-side control which has serve-side Click event. For example `LinkButton`, though it will require some css to look like label. Other option is to generate postback yourself on the client, but this is a bit unusual path.

Comment: Deos it acting like submit button?

Comment: @ofir2471, the link button? Yes, in some sense. Basically any server-side control you use in ASP.NET will submit the whole form, so one can say that they all act like submit button

Comment: I don't want this button/label to use the onsubmit="return send()".

Comment: @ofir2471, but you still want your click to be handled on server? That is controversial. If you want server-side event - the form will be submitted for it, this is how ASP.NET works. So I guess you need to understand first what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Yes, the method loads data from my database

Answer (score 0):

you should define what do you want to do, the click is for show or execute one task or do you want execute to the server side..

For execute one task with the click and not call to the server, you should define the function  javascript and call

For execute call to the server with the event click , you should use wcf ajax for call the server..

or maybe this can help you

http://www.morgantechspace.com/2014/01/Call-Server-Side-function-from-JavaScript-in-ASP-NET.html